# GoogleAnalyticsTracker cannot be resolved to a type in android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I tried to use Google Analytics in my app. I created a account, registered for an app and got the reg number. Added the libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar to my app build path. I tried to use the following code.

```
GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
tracker.setDebug(true);
tracker.startNewSession("UA code",10, this);
```

But I can't import GoogleAnalyticsTracker. It says

> "GoogleAnalyticsTracker cannot be resolved to a type"

**Update1**

I used version1 of Google analytics. And used the following code. From P.T's answer, I waited for more than 24 hours. Still I can't see the user in RealTime overview.
I used the following code in my class file.

```
GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;
tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();    
        tracker.startNewSession("UA code", 20,this);
        tracker.trackPageView("/BS_Splash");
```

**Update 2**

I tired with V2. Used the following code.

```
Context mCtx = this; // Get current context.
        GoogleAnalytics myInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        myInstance.setDebug(true);
        Tracker myNewTracker = myInstance.getTracker("UA code");
        myInstance.setDefaultTracker(myNewTracker);
```

In log cat I got the following, **connection to service failed 1**

```
12-08 13:40:20.423: I/GAV2(22947): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
12-08 13:40:20.423: I/GAV2(22947): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: connect: bindService returned false for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START (has extras) }
12-08 13:40:20.423: W/GAV2(22947): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: Connection to service failed 1
12-08 13:40:20.423: I/GAV2(22947): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: falling back to local store
12-08 13:40:20.433: V/GAV2(22947): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: dispatch running...
12-08 13:40:20.623: V/GAV2(22947): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: ...nothing to dispatch
12-08 13:40:20.633: I/GAV2(22947): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode initiated.
```

Comment: Do any stats or changes show up in the non-real-time section of the GA UI?

Comment: nothing has been shown in the non-real-time section too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try downloading and installing the "legacy" (v1) GA library, or use the new V2 "Advanced" APIs.

The code you've got is assuming the V1 APIs, so its probably easiest to install the V1 library instead.  See:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/resources

Alternatively, you can find an equivalent snippet (that doesn't use EasyTracker) in the "Advanced" section of the V2 API documentation.  See:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced

Specifically, it looks like the global instance lookup now takes an Android `Context` argument, and its just `GoogleAnalytics` not `GoogleAnalyticsTracker`:

```
Context mCtx = this; // Get current context.
GoogleAnalytics myInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
myInstance.setDebug(true);
```

The tracker is now separate as the `Tracker` class:

```
Tracker myNewTracker = myInstance.getTracker("UA-XXXX-2") // A new tracking ID.
```

Comment: thanks P.T. I used V1. Tried the sample application. Replaced the tracking id with mine. After I run my application, I can't see the active users count to 1. And no active session is shown. I just kept my app running in my device.

Comment: You just have to wait.  It can take up to 24 hours for new data to show up in the UI.

Comment: It passed more than 24 hours. Still no updated of the user. I have updated the question.

Comment: thanks.. update2 has worked now. just added one more line..myNewTracker.trackView("Application Started");

Answer (score 0):

Try tracking using `EasyTracker.getInstance().startActivity(this);`

If it doesnt work either recheck the .jar file you added to your libs folder!

Comment: I didn't use EasyTracker. Thats the sample one. I need to implement to my application.

Comment: I want to track my application's Acquisitions and Users, in which country my app is being used.